# How do I point my copied Visual Studio project to a new, empty Subversion repository?

Tags: visual-studio, svn

Seems like somewhere in the copid project folder there must be a file that specifies the URL of the original project repository. If I could find that, I could replace the URL with the URL for the new online Subversion repository.

I've tried the Switch command in Visual SVN, but it seem only to allow choosing a different folder within the original repository, not choosing a completely different repository.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Find the .svn folder and delete it. Then open the project in Visual Studio. Now you are free to add the project to a new repository.